# Why is TypeScript not expanding interface properties?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an interface in TypeScript that I use to type the parameters of a function. However, when I look at the function signature in VSCode it is not showing me the properties of the interface (see below picture), which is not very helpful.

Is there a way to expand the properties to help the developer know what parameters are required by the function?

As a workaround, I tried to add documentation to the function parameters, but as you can see, they do not show up, only the return description and return type

```
export interface ActivitiesParams {
  activity_types?: string[] | string;
  until?: string;
  after?: string;
  direction?: string;
  date?: string;
  page_size?: number;
  page_token?: string;
}
```

Picture:

[image: Intellisense in VSCode]

Comment: The autocomplete with give you the missing keys for the object.

Comment: Please include basic debugging information, like what versions of VSCode and TypeScript on what OS?

Comment: Thanks, Heretic Monkey, indeed they do, which is great. Annoying though that it is not possible to see it just by hovering over the function or by clicking on the ActivityParams in the above picture.

Comment: @HereticMonkey TypeScript version in VSCode is 4.7.3 and on Linux windows distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autocomplete will do that job for you.

Just trigger it within the object you want to build.

[image]

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQWxgQDcFjgBnABUykwFtK4BvAKDjh2LJgE8A%20vzBUA-AC44lGFGQBzANoBdOAB8pM%20QG4OcAK4oEAGwkbZSOTs6Z0qKKennLugCYIowIgghIHmi1ZwLpiofk6BYJhywAKUCABewKZIegwARmgRUTEwEADWwL6SjtpsAL5sbOgGXj5w6BAQABSY4oQ85AhUtPRMAJSsFVWNTSxlAwD0E3DCeERQRgDUlJG4cADu5AAWM1tzelCU0IhIcS54YzMQM7Jy0VBcernYEAxgRsCoQA)